# CORE PLOT add one more Graph in Vertical BarChart

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

Hi I want to make bar chart as  shown here

[image]

I want to plot graph using coreplot example : (coreplot gallery- Vertical Bar Chart)

Currently default code plots the graph as shown below

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I tried adding another graph but didn't work out well.

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:
[image]

In your code you need to add the following:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot
                 field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (plot.identifier==@"locked") {
        switch ( fieldEnum ) {
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
                return (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:
                return [self.lockedPercentage objectAtIndex:index];
            }
    }else if (plot.identifier==@"occupied") {
        switch ( fieldEnum ) {
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
                return (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:
                return [self.occupiedPercentage objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }else if (plot.identifier==@"empty") {
        switch ( fieldEnum ) {
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
                return (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:
                return [self.emptyPercentage objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The lines plot.identifier are here important, they check which data to take, here occupied empty or locked.

Of course you need to set these identifiers, I do this in a -(void) loadgraph:

```
//  Bar plot Locked
CPBarPlot *barPlot = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
barPlot.dataSource = self;
barPlot.baseValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
barPlot.barOffset = 0.0f+viewOffset;
barPlot.barWidth = 15.0f;
barPlot.identifier = @"occupied";

[graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

Here one of my identifier is set. To display values below the x-axe you need to change your range:

```
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(100.0f)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Charles, Thanks for Reply. I could plot more than one bar chart  in original coreplot code but when I tried to implement in my App it giving me error "case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:" Undeclared What could be the problem?

Comment: I can only guess, because I dont have any CPBarPlotFieldBarlength declared in my code. Do you have that in your code? Then try commenting it out, because you dont seem to need it.

Comment: Another possibility could be that your didn´t set your plotspace.yrange or barplot.xrange 
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
 plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(100.0f)];
 plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat([name count])];

Comment: I could solve the problem by renaming  CPBarPlotFieldBarLength to CPBarPlotFieldBarTip  .. Please will you guide me for setting Label to core plot on x and Y axis

Comment: How to set gape(Empty spaces) between two labels as you have wrote 10% 20% on Y axis.

Comment: How To Add table structure below the graph?? as You have added name capacity Empty etc... etc...

Comment: Gotta try a bit more for the labels and so on, I cant just put all my code over here, for the Capacity | ... it´s just an UILabel I inserted and edited, and the table is a UITableView I added to the main View, this has got nothing to do with coreplot.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do this:

```
    // Define some custom labels for the data elements

customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:10], 
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:20],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:30],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:40],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:50],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:60],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:70],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:80],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:90],
                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:100],
                           nil];

NSArray *xAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10%", @"20%", @"30%",
                            @"40%", @"50%", @"60%",@"70%",@"80%",@"90%",@"100%", nil];

labelLocation = 0;
customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];

for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] 
                                                    textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset = y.labelOffset;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    //[newLabel release];
}

y.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
y.majorTickLocations =  [NSSet setWithArray:customTickLocations];
```

You define 2 array, one with the labels and one with the values where to put them, define "CPXAxisLabel"s and put them in another array, and this array you can put on your graph.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks once again for help still I am facing problem in Arranging Bars  HERE in barPlot.barOffset = 0.0f+viewOffset; barPlot.barWidth = 15.0f;  What value you are passing in viewOffset? I am not able to arrange bars properly

Comment: Yes this is not so easy. I did it this way: CGFloat viewOffset =  (1.0f/[name count]) * 15.0f; 15, is the width of my bars, and name count is the same number as the amount of my plotSpace.xRange